# Is There any way DELETE Guest Account?

Tags: windows, guest-account

Is There any way to **DELETE** Guest Account on Windows ?
I don't want to Disable it .

(There is same problem with default Administrator Account.)

Comment: Of course there is, through Computer Management. What windows version are you on?

Comment: @LPChip, Hi, I am using Windows 10 & Server 2012 .

Comment: Okay, will work on both. I'll write you an answer

Comment: I tried with `net users Guest /Delete` but this return an error that it cannot perform this operation on built-in accounts.

Comment: Apparently this cannot be done. Why do you even want to delete them? They're set as disabled anyway, and probably are used to launch certain processes with very limited access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open registry editor and browse to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM\SAM\Domains\Account\Users\Names`, delete the **Guest** key and reboot your computer. You'll see the Guest account was deleted and you can't access it any longer.

Source: https://www.top-password.com/knowledge/delete-windows-built-in-administrator.html

Personally I suggest you make a restore point before deleting the guest account, in case you mess up the registry.

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to set up my family computer so that the Guest account could not be enabled.  I was also working in Windows 7.  The solution I went with, and I recommend this, is to do my own work on a standard (not administrator) account.  That way, if some young mischievous person in my family tries to re-enable the guest account (if I have left my account open and have turned my back for a moment), he will be unsuccessful.

I created a special administrator account called uber-admin.  But I don't use *uber-admin* for my day to day work.  Then I made ALL family members' accounts (including my own) *standard users*.

This has worked well.  The guest account has stayed de-activated.

Answer (score -2):

Go to `C:\Users` and you'll see a folder named Guest. Right-click it and click Delete. Wait for it to be gone. Click Switch User and you'll see the Guest account is fully deleted.